# Can we set values and then use protractor Key chord to paste the values into a text field?

Tags: angularjs, testing, frontend, functional-testing, protractor

I want to paste values into text file in e2e tests using protractor.

In real life a list will be copied from a excel spread sheet and then pasted into the text field.

I am manually copying the list now before I start the protractor test us this command:

```
webElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "v"));
```

I there any way I can set the list then paste the values. I don’t want to copy them each time I launch my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Does simply sending keys like
`element(by.xyz(...)).sendKeys('some text content');`
not suffice your use case?

Comment: I can't answer for OP, but I have the same question and in my case it won't. I have an input field that automatically filters input based on certain rules. While typing it's impossible to add dots and dashes for example, but when you ctrl-v the entire value including dots/dashes is pasted. I want to test that on leaving the field, those characters are filtered out after all.